# Simple c++ recursive explaination needed

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I am currently trying to wrap my head around recursion so I picked a c++ textbook and began to read.  The first couple of pages in the chapter on recursion were easy to understand but then I got to an item that doesn't make sense to me.

```
 int height(node *p)
 {
    if(p==NULL)
       return 0;
    else{
   return 1 + max(height(p->llink),height(p->rlink));

  }
```

If max gives me the greatest of two values, how does max get its arguments from what height it's returning.
If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.....

Comment: Draw a picture of a tree of `node`s and stare at it for a while, thinking about the code in `height`.

Comment: Focus on the base case, draw a tree and work backwards.

Comment: Jacks answer is a good hint about how to progress - the 0 is the termination for the recursion, and the nodes point from parent to the left and right children - and so on...

Comment: have you read the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29 or the simple wiki page: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand recursion you have to think recursively:

- you can understand that an empty tree has height 0
- you can understand that a generic non-empty tree has height 1 + the height of the longest subtree (which can be the one starting from the left or from the right)

Starting from this you can trivially understand the code. If you draw the tree you will see what happens. If you have for example

```
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \  
 D   E
```

- `height(A)` will return `1 + max(height(B), height(C))`
- `height(B)` will return `1 + max(height(D), height(E))`
- `height(C)` will return `1 + max(height(NULL), height(NULL)) = 1`
- `height(D)` will return `1 + max(height(NULL), height(NULL)) = 1`
- `height(E)` will return `1 + max(height(NULL), height(NULL)) = 1`

so

```
height(A) = 1 + max(height(B), height(C)) =
= 1 + max(1 + max(height(D),height(E)), 1) =
= 1 + max(1 + 1, 1) = 1 + max(2, 1) = 3
```

(I omitted calls to `height(NULL)` because they are trivially 0 and otherwise it would have been too much verbose.)

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to function are evaluated before function call.

So your example equivalent could look like the following (which maybe makes more sense?):

```
int height(node *p)
 {
    if(p==NULL)
       return 0;
    else{
       int heightLeftSubtree = height(p->llink);
       int heightRightSubtree = height(p->rlink);
       return 1 + max(heightLeftSubtree, heightRightSubtree);
    }
 }
```